# passing value to next <div> in for loop

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

I have a table which comes from for loop as follow,

```
<c:forEach var="teacher" items="${compositeTeacherInfo}">
    <tr>
        <td ><div class="tabcell">${teacher.getTeacherName()}</div></td>
        <td>${teacher.getFormatedDoj()}</td>
        <td>${teacher.getContactNo()}</td>
        <td ><div class="tabcell">${teacher.getEmail()}</div></td>
        <td><a
            href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/teacher_details/view_teacher_info.jsp?teacherId=${teacher.getTeacherId()}">View</a>
        </td >
        <td><a
            href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/teacher_details/teacher_info.jsp?teacherId=${teacher.getTeacherId()}">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Teacher
                        Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
                    <a
                        href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/TeacherManagementController?flowName=DELETE_TEACHER_INFO&teacherId=${teacher.getTeacherId()}"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

So currently I have 15 rows . what I am trying to do here is, by clicking `delete` link the row has to be delete. Its working fine , row will delete but I have struggling for small change. The change is, Here I used Bootstrap, when I click on `delete` link a bootstrap modal will open and ask for confirmation to delete. This code also is in for loop. So here When modal appears it just display text `Are you sure` but along with it I want to display name for example `Are you sure want to delete "Jack" related record`. The name I can get here is from `${teacher.getTeacherName()}`. when I add it along with modals text always it displays 1st record's name only. How to solve this . Please help me in this.

THANKS...

Comment: please post your sample javascript codes, or put in jsfiddle

Comment: no., I dint use JavaScript here, it is normal html code. I have to pass `teachername` which is in td to `<div class="modal fade">`

Comment: then how to solve this. . .

Comment: where you have added "${teacher.getTeacherName()}" this code?

Comment: it is `<td>` exactly in 3rd line of code.

Comment: it is always displaying first teacher name in all <td> tag? or in all modal window tag?

Comment: in table it display all names in each row but in modal for all record it displays 1st record name. .

Comment: in modal window, where you are displaying teacher name,i cant see any code inside div

Comment: yes ., now I didnt write that here. If I would write , It has to be `<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Teacher                        Record ${teacher.getTeacherName()} related record</h4>` If I write like this, it will show only one name for all records.

Comment: now i got your problem, i will give you solution in 5 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is modal window Div ID,it should be unique , even though if you try to create muliple modal window (DIV) in the for loop. it wont create if the element is ID same.

so,try this . it should work,if teacherId is unique

```
<c:forEach var="teacher" items="${compositeTeacherInfo}">
    <tr>
        <td ><div class="tabcell">${teacher.teacherName}</div></td>
        <td>${teacher.formatedDoj}</td>
        <td>${teacher.cotactNo}</td>
        <td ><div class="tabcell">${teacher.email}</div></td>
        <td><a
            href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/teacher_details/view_teacher_info.jsp?teacherId=${teacher.teacherId}">View</a>
        </td >
        <td><a
            href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pages/teacher_details/teacher_info.jsp?teacherId=${teacher.teacherId}">Edit</a>
        </td
        <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal_${teacher.teacherId}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal_${teacher.teacherId}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete ${teacher.teacherName}
                        Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
                    <a
                        href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/TeacherManagementController?flowName=DELETE_TEACHER_INFO&teacherId=${teacher.teacherId}"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Ya I tried this, this will not work . It gives only 1st record name . .

Comment: tell me more about your problem, only first record of teacher name is displaying or all other record also?

Comment: for example I have 3 rows with names 'user1','user2','user3' in table it shows each name in rows but if I click on delete link on any row the modal shows only user1

Comment: just replace your code with this, and then check.it should work

Comment: oh fine give ur facebook profile id . , we can be in touch.

Comment: just give your skype id, i will send you in that

Comment: my skype id is "bhuvanesh_tarento"

Comment: sorry I dont use skype

Comment: my facebook profile is "Raghavendra Mudenur" , and remove unnecessary comments . .